number of homomorphism from $K_4\to S_4$
I want to  calculate number of homomorphism from $K_4\to S_4$.
let $\phi:K_4\to S_4$ be homomorphism then for each element $x\in S_4$ WHERE $|x|=2$ we have 3 cases  , $ord(\phi(a))=1$ and $ord(\phi(b))=2$, or
$ord(\phi(b))=1$ $ord(\phi(a))=2$ or both $ord(\phi(a))=2~,~ord(\phi(b))=2 $ we have  9 elements of order 2 , for each case  we have 3 homomrphism, then total $9*3=27$ homorphism and $1$ for identity so we have 28 homomorphism with images having order 2 and 1,
now we need homomorphism having images with order four, we have 4 subgroups of order 4 which are not cyclic and since $Aut(K_4)=6$ we got $6*4$ homomorphisms and hence total homomorphisms are $24+28=52$
is it correct?
$K_4$ is Klein-4 group.

"for each element except identity we have 3 homomrphism" - Can you explain why you think so? (As best I can tell, you're assuming the order of $\phi(a)$ equals the order of $\phi(b)$)

i have 3 case let $c\in S_4$ of order 2, then $\phi(a)=e~~and~~ \phi(b)=c$, or  $\phi(b)=e~~and~~ \phi(a)=c$, or  $\phi(a)=c~~and~~ \phi(b)=c$

is klein four group

Okay, you weren't counting how I expected you were.  Where does $\phi(a)=(12), \phi(b)=(34)$ appear in your count?

Again, you need to explain how you're counting.  As best I can tell, you're including functions like $a \mapsto (12), b\mapsto (23)$, which don't generate a homomorphism.

okay yes only disjoint cycles should be included

@BrianMoehring please check now

From the [tag:solution-verification] tag wiki: "A question with this tag should include an explanation for why the argument presented is not convincing enough."

You should say,  in the first part,  for each of the $3$ cases we have $9$ homomorphisms.   And point out how it works in the third case.  Namely that $\phi(a)=\phi(b).$

$\phi(a)=\phi(b)\neq e$ then $\phi(ab)=\phi(a)\phi(b)=e$

I missed your comment earlier.   I do agree with $52.$

First all the images of elements of $K_4$ need to have orders dividing $2.$
(I'll let you supply the reason.)

Now I'll take a stab.
There are four $K_4$'s in $S_4.$  Then use that $\rm Aut(K_4)\cong S_3.$  Composing, that gives $6\cdot4=24.$

Indeed I count $9$ elements of order two in $S_4.$
Now suppose that the image is $\Bbb Z_2.$  There's $9$ choices for the image of $(1,0).$ $(0,1)$ goes to the identity. And we can reverse the generators. That gives $18.$
Both generators can also go to the same element of order two, for $9$ more.

Finally we have the trivial homomorphism.
We get $52.$
